# Active Batch (Active Variable using PowerShell script)

Tags: powershell, activebatch

Currently I am working on Active Batch job variables. how to use active variables using PowerShell script in Active Batch job. can someone Please help me?

Comment: You are _"working on Active Batch job variables"_. Why not show some of your attempt so we may be able to help you with your code??

Answer (score 0):

You can just type the Active Batch variable, eg ${UserName} directly into the PS script:

```
[String]$username = '${UserName}'
```

Note the single quotes rather than double quotes to denote a literal string and to avoid any risk of PS evaluating your variable value.